# In a triangle ABC, (b + c) cos A + (c + a) cos B + (a + b) cos C is equal to

Tags: trigonometry

In a triangle $ABC$

$$(b + c)\cos A + (c + a)\cos B + (a + b)\cos C=?$$

Comment: law of cosine c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab cos(C)                a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc cos(A)                                    b^2=c^2+a^2-2ac cos(B)

Comment: Since you know the Law of Cosines, you can replace $\cos A$, $\cos B$, $\cos C$ in the expression with fractions involving $a$, $b$, $c$, then expand like crazy, and finally find that the result is pretty simple. (There's also far simpler approach.)

Comment: I believe your second term should be "$(c+a)\cos B$".

Answer (score 7):

we know

$$a = b \cos C + c \cos B$$
$$b= a \cos C + c \cos A$$ 
$$c= b \cos A + a \cos B$$ 
adding together we get 
$$(a+b) \cos C + (b+c) \cos A + (c+a) \cos B =a +b+c $$

Answer (score 5):

Hint - draw a diagram of a triangle and see if you can mark a segment of length $b\cos A$ on side $c$ to get a geometric intuition about what is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

We know

acosB + bcosA = c

SO after opening brackets and rearranging them you'll see the answer that is a+b+c

Answer (score -1):

If we write:

1. $b+c=2S-a$
2. $c+a = 2S-b$
3. $a+b= 2S -c$

   Then by expanding the bracket and taking $2S$ as common factor we can write $2S(\cos a +\cos b +\cos c)-(a\cos a+b\cos b+c\cos c)$
   Now since $a+b+c=180 \cos a +\cos b +\cos c = 1+$ 4\sin a/2.sinb/2.sinc/2 and acosa+bcosb +ccosc is $S$.
   Therefore solving further we get $2S(1+4 \sin a/2\sin b/2\sin c/2)-S = S + 4 r/R$  where $r$ is inradius and $R$ is circumradius as $4 \sin a/2 \sin b/2\ sin c/2 is r/R$ .

I'm stuck up after here.

Help me if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).